# Trying to scrape movie contents from IMDB using Node.js dynamic routes . but getting undefined in my output.json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cheerio, node.js-connect

Actually, I am trying to scrape any movie from ImDb using node but after I am making the request but getting the undefined in my output.JSON file (where the movie rating and reviews should come).

First, I am making a request to http://www.imdb.com/find?q= 'movie'
where the movie should be dynamic so that I can query that myself.
and then taking serial no. of movie I am making the request to its URL to scrape the rating and review

but getting undefined ...check the code and please correct it

var express = require('express');

var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var request = require("request");

var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.get('/scrape/:movie' , function(req, res) {

```
var movie = req.params.movie;  
option = {
    protocol : "http:",
    host: "www.imdb.com",
    pathname : "/find " ,
    query: "q=movie"
}
```

// here i am requesting the http://www.imdb.com/find?q= 'movie'

```
 request(option,function(error,request,body) {
     if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         var $ =cheerio.load(body);
         var select=$(".result_text").attr("href");
     }
 });
```

// here i am extracting the serial number of the first found movie from the imdb search .

```
urls = "http://www.imdb.com/ + 'select' ";

request(urls, function(error,response,body) {
    
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ =cheerio.load(body);
        var title, release, rating, review;
        var json = { title : "",review : ""};

        json.title =$(".title").text(); 
        json.review= $(".reviewSection").text();
    }

    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 7), function(error) {
        if(!error)
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');

    });
    
    res.send('Check your console!');
});
```

});
app.listen(3000);

Comment: First thing that jumps to the eye: should be `"q=" + movie`, and not `"q=movie"` ^^

Comment: pls  make it  work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code as follows. There were several issues getting in your way. Be sure to console log if you don't know what they are.

```
var express = require('express');
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape/:movie' , function(req, res) {

var movie = req.params.movie;
var url = "http://www.imdb.com/find?q=" + movie;
```

Here just set the url to what you want it to be and call it in the request function

```
 request(url, function(error, response, body) {
```

Make sure to think about what you call each variable. If the above was set to 'request,' you won't be able to make the request call below because its been reset to response.

```
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var select = $('.result_text').first().children()[0].attribs['href']
 }
 var url = 'http://www.imdb.com' + select;
```

Here you need to go to the actual website, open the developer console, and figure out the exact query selectors you want to use.

Again just set the url to what you want it to be. in this case, select shows up as '/title/tt0357413' (for anchorman), so adjust your url accordingly.

---

You need to put this next request inside of the request function above because the above function is still working when this one is called outside of it. You need to make sure that the new url variable is set before you make the second request call.

```
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
   if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var $ =cheerio.load(body);
     var title, review;
     var json = { title : "",review : ""};

     json.title = $("h1").text();
     json.review = $('.imdbRating').text()
   }
```

Again for these two variables, make sure you open the developer console and figure out the exact selectors you want to use.

```
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 7), function(error) {
         if(!error)
         console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
       });

       res.send('Check your console!');
    });
  });
}); app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script using [scavenger](https://github.com/pietrovismara/scavenger), it takes the title and metacritic score for the movie *brazil*:

```js
const scavenger = require('scavenger');

const baseUrl = "http://www.imdb.com";
const searchMovieUrl = `${baseUrl}/find?q=cell`;

const extractMovieUrl = scavenger.createExtractor({
    scope: 'tr.findResult',
    fields: {
        url: {
            selector: 'td.result_text a',
            attribute: 'href'
        }
    }
});

const extractInfo = scavenger.createExtractor({
    fields: {
        title: 'div.title_wrapper h1',
        score: 'div.metacriticScore'
    }
});

scavenger.scrape(searchMovieUrl, extractMovieUrl)
.then((movies) => {
    return scavenger.scrape(`${baseUrl}/${movies[0].url}`, extractInfo);
})
.then((movieInfo) => {
    console.log(movieInfo);
    // [ { title: 'Brazil (1985)', score: '88' } ]
});
```

You can adapt it to your server code easily.